# Making a fixed div scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-position

I do not have any example for this however it's really not needed for this question. Is it possible to make a div scrollable left and right but not up and down? I understand that a relative layout does both, and a fixed doesn't move at all.

- Requirement must be done through HTML and CSS only.

Comment: I think if you make the div wider than the screen width it will show scroll automatically

Comment: That's true, but only if its absolute, which absolute will move in any direction.

Comment: I havent tried it but if you set max-height to 100vh and make the div larger than the container, or the screen size it might work also with relative position. But I have no evidence at the moment. Overflow: hidden will disable scroll, whereby overflow: auto allows scrolling.

Comment: That makes sense, and should work. However will it create a new an extra scrollbar?

Comment: I am not sure. But you can test it out. the browser should show a scroll bar by default if the width is more than 100%. Sorry, but I have no working example at the moment.

Comment: No problem, your idea works, however creates another scrollbar, meaning that the body doesn't scroll with the container.

Comment: You mean the browser scroll bar? Yes , of course. I don't understand how should the body scroll?

Comment: What I mean is that they would all scroll together so this div would stay on the screen up and down scrolling but when i scroll the entire webpage left to right it will move with the rest of the webpage. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: I think know I understand better what you mean. So when user scrolls left, right you want a div to move with the scrolling? I am not sure how to do this in css or if it is possible with css only. I would use Javascript for this one may be. Sorry.

Comment: Exactly, I posted this because I wasn't sure if it was possible for css, I know that it is possible in JS though.

Comment: Solved for some browsers - Use the sticky position. CSS "position: sticky"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, the only issue is that it doesn't work with all browsers:

```
div {
    position: sticky;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit too short (but can't answer without more information or markup, or JSFIDDLE to apply)

CSS

```
div {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The comments on the post explain it in more depth, however with my wording you did answer the question.